# Prove that $5$ divides $4^{6n}+8^{{2n}^2}-(-1)^{{n}^3}-1$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, divisibility

I am doing this proof by induction but I seem to be getting stuck.

My attempt:

For $n=0$, we can see it is true as $5|0$.

Setting $M_n = 4^{6n}+8^{2n^2}-(-1)^{n^3}-1$

We will assume $5|M_n$.

Now to show it is true for $n+1$:

$M_{n+1}= 4^{6(n+1)}+8^{2(n+1)^2}-(-1)^{(n+1)^3}-1$.

I'm aware I need to get factors of $M_n$ and $5$ out but it gets too messy so I feel as though I'm on the wrong track.

I expanded to find: $\bbox[yellow]{4^{6n}}\cdot4^6+\bbox[yellow]{8^{2n^2}}\cdot8^{2n}\cdot8-\bbox[yellow]{(-1)^{n^3}}\cdot(-1)^{3n^2+3n+1}-1$

I can see the highlighted terms make up $M_n$ but I don't see what I can do with that. I tried to rewrite the highlighted parts in terms of $M_n$ but it became way too messy, so I feel like there is an easier route.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $M_n = 2^{12n}+2^{12n^2}-(-1)^n-1$

Comment: Why $2^{12n^2}$ and not $2^{6n^2}$?

Comment: $8^{(2n)^2} = 8^{4n^2} = 2^{3(4n^2)} = 2^{12n^2}$

Comment: it's $8^{2n^2}$ not $8^{(2n)^2}$ @DHMO, and $8^{2n^2}=2^{6n^2}$.

Comment: @k.Vijay You can check his code which writes `8^{{2n}^2}`

Comment: That's my mistake with coding! I'll fix it now. But yes there are no brackets. In any case however, by using this new $M_n$ I still find myself stuck at the same situation..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Work mod 5. Thus
$$
4^{6n} + 8^{2n^2} - (-1)^{n^3} - 1
\equiv
(-1)^{6n} + 3^{2n^2} - (-1)^{n^3} - 1
\equiv 3^{2n^2} - (-1)^{n^3} \pmod{5}.
$$
Next write $3^{2n^2}$ as $9^{n^2}$ to get
$$
3^{2n^2} - (-1)^{n^3}
= 9^{n^2} - (-1)^{n^3}
\equiv (-1)^{n^2} - (-1)^{n^3} \pmod{5}.
$$
It only remains to note that this last quantity is $0$ by considering the cases of $n$ even and $n$ odd.

Comment: $(-1)^{n^k}=(-1)^n$, so it's not really necessary to distinguish cases.

Comment: @egreg Well, what you write is true because $n^k\equiv n\pmod2$ for all $n$ and all $k\ge1$, but wouldn't one verify this by noting that it's true for even $n$ and it's true for odd $n$. Alternatively, I guess one could factor $n^k-n=n(n^{k-1}-1)$ and observe that the factors have different parity.

Comment: This might be a trivial question, but as the question states 'Prove', does showing it to be true under mod $5$ qualify as a full proof?

Comment: @N.K The following two statements are equivalent (directly from the definition of modular arithmetic):  (1) The integer $N$ is divisible by the integer $m$. (2) The congrucence $N\equiv 0\pmod{m}$ holds. So yes, proving that the OP's quantity is congruent to 0 modulo 5 is exactly the same as proving that it is divisible by 5.

Answer (score 3):

it is simple without induction since $$4^{6n}=(4^6)^n\equiv 1 \mod 5$$, $$8^{2n^2}\equiv (-1)^{n^2}\equiv (-1)^{n^2}$$ thus we have $$M_n\equiv (-1)^{n^2}-(-1)^{n^3}\equiv 0 \mod 5$$

Comment: Thank you! Just out of curiosity, with this type of question i.e  does $n|f(x)$ where $n$ is a positive integer and $f(x)$ is a function, is it always easier to use modular congruence as opposed to proof by induction?  Or is it very dependent on the case at hand?

Comment: it is easier to use modular arithmetic